Hardware Component stops writing after ~25 seconds. Also initiates with extremely high values
Whenever I start my motor with my own hardware component it starts writing extremely high values that I haven't set. (See log)
After that is also somehow stops writing after approximately 25 seconds. I have already tried increasing the watchdog timer but unfortunately it is still happening. My Hardware Component is based on a Driver that is written for the same motor controller. Has anyone got an idea for either problem? I have included the codebase from the driver, which has none of these issues, and my own hardware component.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715867762.767254622] [DiffDriveRoboteqHardware]: [ROBOTEQ] left: -2147483648 right: -2147483648

FIX FOR HIGH VALUES:
I have found the fix for the first problem:
I was initiating my hw_commands_ vector with QuietNans which was causing the issue. I have now changed it to:
hw_commands_.resize(info_.joints.size(), 0.0);


My Hardware Component:
#include "diffdrive_roboteq/diffdrive_roboteq.hpp"

#include "hardware_interface/lexical_casts.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_type_values.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

namespace diffdrive_roboteq
{
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::on_init(const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo & info)
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "on_init active");
            
            if (
                hardware_interface::SystemInterface::on_init(info) !=
                hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS)
            {
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
            }

            conf_.serial_port = info_.hardware_parameters["serial_port"];
            conf_.baud_rate = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["baud_rate"]);
            conf_.closed_loop = (info_.hardware_parameters["closed_loop"] == "true");
            conf_.diff_drive_mode = (info_.hardware_parameters["diff_drive_mode"] == "true");
            conf_.wheel_circumference = hardware_interface::stod(info_.hardware_parameters["wheel_circumference"]);
            conf_.track_width = hardware_interface::stod(info_.hardware_parameters["track_width"]);
            conf_.max_rpm = hardware_interface::stod(info_.hardware_parameters["max_rpm"]);
            conf_.frequency = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["frequency"]);
            conf_.cmd_vel_topic = info_.hardware_parameters["cmd_vel_topic"];
            
            hw_positions_.resize(info_.joints.size(), 0.0);
            hw_velocities_.resize(info_.joints.size(), 0.0);
            hw_commands_.resize(info_.joints.size(), 0.0);

            for (const hardware_interface::ComponentInfo & joint : info_.joints)
            {
                if (joint.command_interfaces.size() != 1)
                {
                RCLCPP_FATAL(
                    rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),
                    "Joint '%s' has %zu command interfaces found. 1 expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
                    joint.command_interfaces.size());
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
                }

                if (joint.command_interfaces[0].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY)
                {
                RCLCPP_FATAL(
                    rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),
                    "Joint '%s' have %s command interfaces found. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
                    joint.command_interfaces[0].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY);
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
                }

                if (joint.state_interfaces.size() != 2)
                {
                RCLCPP_FATAL(
                    rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),
                    "Joint '%s' has %zu state interface. 2 expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
                    joint.state_interfaces.size());
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
                }

                if (joint.state_interfaces[0].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION)
                {
                RCLCPP_FATAL(
                    rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),
                    "Joint '%s' have '%s' as first state interface. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
                    joint.state_interfaces[0].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION);
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
                }

                if (joint.state_interfaces[1].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY)
                {
                RCLCPP_FATAL(
                    rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),
                    "Joint '%s' have '%s' as second state interface. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
                    joint.state_interfaces[1].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY);
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
                }
            }

            return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
        }

    /**
    * @brief Exports the state interfaces provided by the hardware.
    *
    * This method defines and exports the state interfaces for each joint. Each joint
    * is associated with position and velocity state interfaces. These interfaces allow
    * the hardware to communicate its state (position and velocity) to the controller.
    * The full interface names follow the structure <joint_name>/<interface_type>.
    * 
    * @return std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> A vector containing the state interfaces for all joints.
    */
    std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::export_state_interfaces()
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "export_state_interfaces active...");
        // Create a vector to hold the state interfaces
        std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> state_interfaces;

        // Loop over each joint in the hardware info
        for (auto i = 0u; i < info_.joints.size(); i++)
        {
            // Add position state interface for the current joint
            state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
                info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &hw_positions_[i]));
            
            // Add velocity state interface for the current joint
            state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
                info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &hw_velocities_[i]));
        }

        // Return the vector of state interfaces
        return state_interfaces;
    }

    /**
    * @brief Exports the command interfaces provided by the hardware.
    *
    * This method defines and exports the command interfaces for each joint. Each joint
    * 
    * @return std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> A vector containing the command interfaces for all joints.
    */
    std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::export_command_interfaces()
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "export_command_interfaces active...");
        // Create a vector to hold the command interfaces
        std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> command_interfaces;

        // Loop over each joint in the hardware info
        for (auto i = 0u; i < info_.joints.size(); i++)
        {
            // Add velocity command interface for the current joint
            command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(
                info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &hw_commands_[i]));
        }

        // Return the vector of command interfaces
        return command_interfaces;
    }

    /**
    * @brief Configures the hardware communication.
    * 
    * This method sets up the communication to the hardware and prepares it for activation.
    * It initializes the serial port with the specified settings such as port name and baud rate.
    * 
    * @param previous_state The previous lifecycle state of the hardware component.
    * @return CallbackReturn Returns a status indicating the success or failure of the configuration process.
    */
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::on_configure(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
    {   
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "on_configure active...");
        try {
            // Set up the serial port with the specified configuration parameters
            ser_.setPort(conf_.serial_port);
            ser_.setBaudrate(conf_.baud_rate);
            serial::Timeout timeout = serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(1000);
            ser_.setTimeout(timeout);
            ser_.open();
        } catch (serial::IOException &e) {
            // If an exception occurs during port setup (e.g., unable to open port), log an error message and shutdown the ROS node
            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Unable to open port " << conf_.serial_port << ".");
            return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }

        if (ser_.isOpen()) {
            // If the port is open, log a message indicating successful initialization
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial Port " << conf_.serial_port << " initialized.");
        } else {
            // If the port is not open, log a message indicating failure and shutdown the ROS node
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial Port " << conf_.serial_port << " is not open.");
            return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }

        return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
    }


    /**
    * @brief Cleans up the hardware communication.
    * 
    * This method closes the serial port to clean up the hardware communication interface.
    * 
    * @param previous_state The previous lifecycle state of the hardware component.
    * @return CallbackReturn Returns a status indicating the success or failure of the cleanup process.
    */
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::on_cleanup(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "on_cleanup active...");
        // Log a message indicating that the cleanup process is starting
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Cleaning up ...please wait...");
        
        try {
            // Check if the serial port is open and close it if so
            if (ser_.isOpen()) {
                ser_.close();
                RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial Port " << conf_.serial_port << " closed.");
            } else {
                // Log a warning if the serial port was not open
                RCLCPP_WARN_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial Port " << conf_.serial_port << " was not open.");
            }
        } catch (const serial::IOException &e) {
            // Log an error if an exception occurs during the closing process
            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Error while closing serial port: " << e.what());
        }

        // Log a message indicating successful cleanup
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Successfully cleaned up!");

        return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
    }


    /**
    * @brief Activates the hardware.
    * 
    * This method prepares the hardware for operation by ensuring the serial port is open and 
    * configuring the hardware settings such as stopping the motors, enabling the watchdog timer,
    * setting the motor operating mode, and setting encoder counts. If any step fails, it logs an error 
    * and returns an error status.
    * 
    * @param previous_state The previous lifecycle state of the hardware component.
    * @return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn Returns a status indicating the success or failure of the activation process.
    */
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::on_activate(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "on_activate active...");
        // Check if the serial port is open
        if (!ser_.isOpen()) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial port is not open. Unable to activate.");
            return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }

        // Stop motors and configure hardware
        try {
            // Stop motors
            RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "on_activate active");
            ser_.write("!G 1 0\r");
            ser_.write("!G 2 0\r");
            ser_.write("!S 1 0\r");
            ser_.write("!S 2 0\r");
            ser_.flush();

            // Enable watchdog timer
            ser_.write("^RWD 1000\r");
            ser_.flush();

            // Set motor operating mode
            if (!conf_.closed_loop) {
                ser_.write("^MMOD 1 0\r");
                ser_.write("^MMOD 2 0\r");
            } else {
                ser_.write("^MMOD 1 1\r");
                ser_.write("^MMOD 2 1\r");
            }
            ser_.flush();

            // Set encoder counts
            std::stringstream right_enccmd;
            std::stringstream left_enccmd;
            right_enccmd << "^EPPR 1 " << 1024 << "\r";
            left_enccmd << "^EPPR 2 " << 1024 << "\r";
            ser_.write(right_enccmd.str());
            ser_.write(left_enccmd.str());
            ser_.flush();
        } catch (const serial::IOException &e) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Error while configuring hardware: " << e.what());
            return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }

        return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
    }

    // Implement the on_deactivate method, which does the opposite of on_activate.
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::on_deactivate(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Deactivating ...please wait...");
        // TODO
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Successfully deactivated!");

        return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
    }

    // Implement the read method getting the states from the hardware and storing them to internal variables defined in export_state_interfaces.
    hardware_interface::return_type DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::read(const rclcpp::Time & /*time*/, const rclcpp::Duration & period)
    {
        try {
            RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "read() active...");
            // Check if the serial port is open
            if (!ser_.isOpen()) {
                RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial port is not open. Unable to activate.");
                return hardware_interface::return_type::ERROR;
            }
            
            // TODO
            return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
        } catch (const std::exception &e) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Exception in write(): " << e.what());
            return hardware_interface::return_type::ERROR;
        }   
    }

    /**
    * @brief Writes commands to the hardware.
    * 
    * This method sends commands to the hardware based on the control mode configured
    * (open loop or closed loop). For closed-loop mode, it calculates the motor speed
    * (in rpm) from the commanded wheel speeds (in m/s) and sends the speed commands to
    * the motors. For open-loop mode, it directly sends the commands to the motors.
    * 
    * @param time The current time.
    * @param period The time elapsed since the last write operation.
    * @return hardware_interface::return_type Returns a status indicating the success or failure of the write operation.
    */
    hardware_interface::return_type diffdrive_roboteq ::DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::write(
    const rclcpp::Time & /*time*/, const rclcpp::Duration & /*period*/)
    {
        try {
            RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "write() active...");
            // Check if the serial port is open
            if (!ser_.isOpen()) {
                RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial port is not open. Unable to activate.");
                return hardware_interface::return_type::ERROR;
            }
            
            // Prepare the command string
            std::stringstream cmd_str;
            

            // Prepare the speed floats
            float left_speed  = hw_commands_[0];
            float right_speed = hw_commands_[1];

            if(conf_.closed_loop) {
                // Calculate motor speeds (in rpm) from commanded wheel speeds (in m/s)
                int32_t left_rpm  = left_speed  *60.0 / conf_.wheel_circumference;
                int32_t right_rpm = right_speed *60.0 / conf_.wheel_circumference;

                // Log the motor speeds
                RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),"[ROBOTEQ] left: %9d right: %9d", left_rpm, right_rpm);
                
                // Construct the command string for closed-loop mode
                cmd_str << "!S 1"
                        << " " << left_rpm << "_"
                        << "!S 2"
                        << " " << right_rpm << "_";
            }
            else {
                // motor power (scale 0-1000)
                float right_power = right_speed *1000.0 *60.0/ (conf_.wheel_circumference * conf_.max_rpm);
                float left_power  = left_speed  *1000.0 *60.0/ (conf_.wheel_circumference * conf_.max_rpm);
                           RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),"[ROBOTEQ] left: %9d right: %9d", (int)left_power, (int)right_power);
                
                cmd_str << "!G 1"
                        << " " << (int)left_power << "_"
                        << "!G 2"
                        << " " << (int)right_power << "_";
            }
            // Send the command string to the hardware
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),cmd_str.str());
            ser_.write(cmd_str.str());
            ser_.flush();
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),cmd_str.str());

            // Return success status
            return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
        } catch (const std::exception &e) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Exception in write(): " << e.what());
            return hardware_interface::return_type::ERROR;
        }
    }
} // namespace diffdrive_roboteq
#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp"
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(diffdrive_roboteq::DiffDriveRoboteqHardware, hardware_interface::SystemInterface)

The working driver:
#include "roboteq_controller/roboteq_controller_node.h"

// static const std::string tag {"[RoboteQ] "};
static const std::string tag {""};

void RoboteqDriver::declare(){
    declare_parameter<std::string>("serial_port", "dev/ttyUSB0");
    declare_parameter("baudrate", 112500);
    declare_parameter("closed_loop", false);
    declare_parameter("diff_drive_mode", false);
    declare_parameter("wheel_circumference", 0.0);
    declare_parameter("track_width", 0.0);
    declare_parameter("max_rpm", 0.0);
    declare_parameter<int>("frequency", 0);
    declare_parameter<std::string>("cmd_vel_topic", "cmd_vel");
}

void RoboteqDriver::init(){
    RCLCPP_INFO(get_logger(), "Creating");
    get_parameter("frequency", frequency_);

    get_parameter("serial_port", serial_port_);
    get_parameter("baudrate", baudrate_);

    get_parameter("closed_loop", closed_loop_);
    get_parameter("diff_drive_mode", diff_drive_mode_);
    
    get_parameter("wheel_circumference", wheel_circumference_);
    get_parameter("track_width", track_width_);
    get_parameter("max_rpm", max_rpm_);
    get_parameter("cmd_vel_topic", cmd_vel_topic_);

    RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "cmd_vel:" << cmd_vel_topic_);

    if (closed_loop_){
        RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "In CLOSED-LOOP mode!!!! serial port:" << serial_port_);
    }
    else{
        RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "In OPEN-LOOP mode!!!!");
    }

    if (wheel_circumference_ <=0.0 ){
        RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Inproper configuration! wheel_circumference need to be greater than zero.");
    }
    if (track_width_ <=0.0 ){
        RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Inproper configuration! track_width need to be greater than zero.");
    }
    if ( max_rpm_ <=0.0 ){
        RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Inproper configuration! max_rpm need to be greater than zero.");
    }

    if (frequency_ <= 0.0){
        RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Inproper configuration! \'frequency\' need to be greater than zero.");
    }

    // Nested params for queries
    // get_parameter();

    auto param_interface = this->get_node_parameters_interface();
    std::map<std::string, rclcpp::ParameterValue> params = param_interface->get_parameter_overrides();

    RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(this->get_logger(), tag << "queries:" );

    for (auto iter = params.begin(); iter != params.end(); iter++){
        std::size_t pos = iter->first.find("query");
        if (pos != std::string::npos && 
            iter->second.get_type() == rclcpp::ParameterType::PARAMETER_STRING){
            std::string topic = iter->first.substr (pos+ 6);    
            auto query = iter->second.to_value_msg().string_value;
            
            queries_[topic] =  query;
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "%15s : %s",  topic.c_str(), query.c_str() );
        }
    }
}


RoboteqDriver::RoboteqDriver(const rclcpp::NodeOptions &options): Node("roboteq_controller", options),
    wheel_circumference_(0.),
    track_width_(0.),
    max_rpm_(0.),
    frequency_(0),
    serial_port_("dev/ttyUSB0"),
    baudrate_(112500),
    closed_loop_(false),
    diff_drive_mode_(false),
    cmd_vel_topic_("cmd_vel"){
    
    declare();
    init();

    if (diff_drive_mode_){
        cmd_vel_sub_ = create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>(
                                        cmd_vel_topic_, rclcpp::SystemDefaultsQoS(),
                                        std::bind(&RoboteqDriver::cmdVelCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }
    else{
        cmd_vel_sub_ = create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist>(
                                        cmd_vel_topic_, rclcpp::SystemDefaultsQoS(),
                                        std::bind(&RoboteqDriver::powerCmdCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    }

    // Initiate communication to serial port
    try{
        ser_.setPort(serial_port_);
        ser_.setBaudrate(baudrate_);
        serial::Timeout timeout = serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(1000);
        ser_.setTimeout(timeout);
        ser_.open();
    }
    catch (serial::IOException &e){
        RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Unable to open port " << serial_port_);
        rclcpp::shutdown();
    }

    if (ser_.isOpen()){
        RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Serial Port " << serial_port_ << " initialized");
    }
    else{
        RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Serial Port " << serial_port_ << " is not open");
        rclcpp::shutdown();
    }

    cmdSetup();

    run();
}


void RoboteqDriver::cmdSetup(){
    // stop motors
    ser_.write("!G 1 0\r");
    ser_.write("!G 2 0\r");
    ser_.write("!S 1 0\r");
    ser_.write("!S 2 0\r");
    ser_.flush();

    // // disable echo
    // ser.write("^ECHOF 1\r");
    // ser.flush();

    // enable watchdog timer (1000 ms) to stop if no connection
    ser_.write("^RWD 1000\r");

    // set motor operating mode (1 for closed-loop speed)
    if (!closed_loop_){
        // open-loop speed mode
        ser_.write("^MMOD 1 0\r");
        ser_.write("^MMOD 2 0\r");
        ser_.flush();
    }
    else{
        // closed-loop speed mode
        ser_.write("^MMOD 1 1\r");
        ser_.write("^MMOD 2 1\r");
        ser_.flush();
    }

    // set encoder counts (ppr)
    std::stringstream right_enccmd;
    std::stringstream left_enccmd;
    right_enccmd << "^EPPR 1 " << 1024 << "\r";
    left_enccmd << "^EPPR 2 " << 1024 << "\r";
    ser_.write(right_enccmd.str());
    ser_.write(left_enccmd.str());
    ser_.flush();
}


void RoboteqDriver::run(){
    // initializeServices();
    std::stringstream ss0, ss1;
    ss0 << "^echof 1_";
    ss1 << "# c_/\"DH?\",\"?\"";

    for (auto item : queries_){
        RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Publish topic: " << item.first);
        query_pub_.push_back(create_publisher<roboteq_interfaces::msg::ChannelValues>(item.first, 100));

        std::string cmd = item.second;
        ss1 << cmd << "_";
    }

    ss1 << "# " << frequency_ << "_";
    
    ser_.write(ss0.str());
    ser_.write(ss1.str());
    ser_.flush();
    

    serial_read_pub_ = create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("read", rclcpp::SystemDefaultsQoS());

    std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli> dt (1000/frequency_);
    timer_pub_ = create_wall_timer(dt, std::bind(&RoboteqDriver::queryCallback, this) );
}


void RoboteqDriver::powerCmdCallback(const geometry_msgs::msg::Twist &msg){
    std::stringstream cmd_str;
    if (closed_loop_){
        cmd_str << "!S 1"
                << " " << msg.linear.x << "_"
                << "!S 2"
                << " " << msg.angular.z << "_";
    }
    else{
        cmd_str << "!G 1"
                << " " << msg.linear.x << "_"
                << "!G 2"
                << " " << msg.angular.z << "_";
    }
    ser_.write(cmd_str.str());
    ser_.flush();
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(),"[ROBOTEQ] left: %9.3f right: %9.3f", msg.linear.x, msg.angular.z);
    // RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(this->get_logger(),cmd_str.str());
}


void RoboteqDriver::cmdVelCallback(const geometry_msgs::msg::Twist &msg){
    // wheel speed (m/s)
    float right_speed = msg.linear.x + track_width_ * msg.angular.z / 2.0;
    float left_speed  = msg.linear.x - track_width_ * msg.angular.z / 2.0;
    
    // RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(),("[ROBOTEQ] left: %.3f right: %.3f", left_speed, right_speed);
    std::stringstream cmd_str;
    if (!closed_loop_){
        // motor power (scale 0-1000)
        float right_power = right_speed *1000.0 *60.0/ (wheel_circumference_ * max_rpm_);
        float left_power  = left_speed  *1000.0 *60.0/ (wheel_circumference_ * max_rpm_);
    
        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(),"[ROBOTEQ] left: %9d right: %9d", (int)left_power, (int)right_power);
        
        cmd_str << "!G 1"
                << " " << (int)left_power << "_"
                << "!G 2"
                << " " << (int)right_power << "_";
    }
    else{
        // motor speed (rpm)
        int32_t right_rpm = right_speed *60.0 / wheel_circumference_;
        int32_t left_rpm  = left_speed  *60.0 / wheel_circumference_;

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(),"[ROBOTEQ] left: %9d right: %9d", left_rpm, right_rpm);
        cmd_str << "!S 1"
                << " " << left_rpm << "_"
                << "!S 2"
                << " " << right_rpm << "_";
    }

    ser_.write(cmd_str.str());
    ser_.flush();
    // RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(this->get_logger(),cmd_str.str());
}

void RoboteqDriver::queryCallback(){
    auto current_time = this->now();
    if (ser_.available()){
        std_msgs::msg::String result;

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(locker);

        result.data = ser_.read(ser_.available());

        // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> unlock(locker);


        serial_read_pub_->publish(result);
        
        boost::replace_all(result.data, "\r", "");
        boost::replace_all(result.data, "+", "");

        std::vector<std::string> fields;
        
        boost::split(fields, result.data, boost::algorithm::is_any_of("D"));
        if (fields.size() < 2){

            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Empty data:{" << result.data << "}");
        }
        else if (fields.size() >= 2){
            std::vector<std::string> fields_H;
            for (int i = fields.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
                if (fields[i][0] == 'H'){
                    try{
                        fields_H.clear();
                        boost::split(fields_H, fields[i], boost::algorithm::is_any_of("?"));
                        if ( fields_H.size() >= query_pub_.size() + 1){
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (const std::exception &e){
                        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
                        RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Finding query output in :" << fields[i]);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (fields_H.size() > 0 && fields_H[0] == "H"){
                for (int i = 0; i < fields_H.size() - 1; ++i){
                    std::vector<std::string> sub_fields_H;
                    boost::split(sub_fields_H, fields_H[i + 1], boost::algorithm::is_any_of(":"));
                    
                    roboteq_interfaces::msg::ChannelValues msg;
                    msg.header.stamp = current_time;

                    for (int j = 0; j < sub_fields_H.size(); j++){
                        try{
                            msg.value.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<int>(sub_fields_H[j]));
                        }
                        catch (const std::exception &e){
                            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Garbage data on Serial");
                            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(this->get_logger(), result.data);
                            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(this->get_logger(), e.what());
                            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
                        }
                    }
                    query_pub_[i]->publish(msg);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            RCLCPP_WARN_STREAM(this->get_logger(),tag << "Unknown:{" << result.data << "}");
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<RoboteqDriver>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```


what do you mean with "stops writing"? In what state is the component then ros2 control list_hardware_components?

It is still in active state: state: id=3 label=active.
It stops performing the write()-read() loop and ends with this:
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715935914.102981467] [DiffDriveRoboteqHardware]: read() active...
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715935914.106951435] [DiffDriveRoboteqHardware]: write() active...
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715935914.106974017] [DiffDriveRoboteqHardware]: [ROBOTEQ] left: 0 right: 0

uncomment the serial commands and add logging output. Maybe the update rate is too high or something similar. do you run it at the same frequency as the "working driver"?

Yes, the configuration for the motor controller is exactly the same. I am also pretty sure that frequency is only being used for reading (which I haven't implemented yet), so that shouldn't be an issue.
As for uncommenting the serial commands, I am not quite sure what you are reffering to. I have updated the code for my hardware component above.

The controller manager calls the write method with its update rate. This is then different from your driver, if the commands are sent only if it gets a new command.
Uncomment those lines and see if something changes:
        ser_.write(cmd_str.str());
        ser_.flush();


Yes, I understand the controller manager calls the write method with its update rate, which I have set to 50. The lines you are referring to were never uncommented to begin with, but I have added extra logging before, in between and after: ser_.write(cmd_str.str()); ser_.flush();. What happens is the following: right before the read()-write() loop stops it logs the first and second print statement but not the third, so ser_.flush(); is not being executed.

This is exactly what I was expecting, it seems that your serial port hangs after some time. Try reducing the cm update rate, does it change the behavior?

I think you are spot on to be fair. I have reduced the controller manager update rate from 50 -> 20 but still after about 60 seconds it hangs / doesn't execute the ser_.flush.
So lowering the cm update rate did increase the time for which its working, but it still stops in the end.

Since then I have tried lowering the controller manager update rate even more and the lower it goes, the longer it works without hanging and eventually stopping. Would you know why this is happening and how I could change it so it runs infinitely without hanging?

Since it always hangs when trying to execute flush(), I have had a look at what flush() exactly does and this is it:
void Serial::flush ()
{
ScopedReadLock rlock(this->pimpl_);
ScopedWriteLock wlock(this->pimpl_);
pimpl_->flush ();
}
To me it seems that it somehow gets stuck on a lock, so it could maybe be a deadlock. Do you have any idea when it comes to this?

which serial implementation do you use? There is no package called serial being released for ROS 2, nor a rosdep key registered for it.

I am using William Woodall's serial lib: https://github.com/wjwwood/serial/tree/main?tab=MIT-1-ov-file . Okay quite a bit of progress over here, I have looked into the documentation for the serial library and have had a look at the flush() function. This flushes both input and output buffers. As I am having trouble with the write() function I have tried using flushInput() which only flushes the input buffers and this has as far as I can see fixed the issue. :D
Thanks for helping me figure this one out.

you're welcome. I added a brief summery as answer, can you mark the question as answered pls? (not the up-arrow, but the green tick)

Summary from the discussion in the comments above:
The calls of the serial library in the write() method blocks the execution (depending on the update rate of the controller_manager earlier or later)
        ser_.write(cmd_str.str());
        ser_.flush();

Removing the flush seems to solve this.
